# How can I install separate language and region for non-admin Gnome user on Debian Bullseye?

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, language

I have created a non-admin user in Debian-Bullseye. In the Region & language section for both the root user and the new non-admin user, there's only English listed. When I click on the three dots to get other languages, no list shows up. Typing the language in the search bar doesn't return anything either. Similarly, in the formats section, it only shows United States, with no way to add locales. What I want to do is have English for the admin user and complete German environment, locale and input language for the non-admin user.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: I ran sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales and selected the desired the language. Now they're available in the selector list to choose.
There's however now another problem. Setting both Language and Formats to German and restarting the session has no effect. I will create a new question for that.